# Error connecting to SQL server through string, not recognising user name or password

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dataadapter

the problem I am having is connecting to an account on my sql server (2005) from an ASP.NET application.

Ive tried using the default sa login and users ive created already also the setting of the sql management studio are set to mixed properties, I have the string connection in the webconfig as well but also doesnt work.

c# code

```
    //string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string conStr = @"server=JAMES-PC\SQLEXPRESS; database=projectDB; uid=james; password=password;";
    string query = "SELECT [TaskID], [Task], [Start Date] AS Start_Date, [End Date] AS End_Date, [Priority], [Time Allowance] AS Time_Allowance, [Details], [Catagory] FROM [schedulerData0]";
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conStr);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    dataAdapt.Fill(table);
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

The error message I receive is:

Login failed for user 'james'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Any help appreciated
James

Comment: Maybe you need IntegratedSecurity=SSPI ?

Comment: Set IntegratedSecurity=false when you are using a sql account

Comment: where would this code go in the webconfig? or somewhere within management studios

Comment: alright got it going thank you for response

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL SERVER configured for `Windows Only` connections and you current windows user not associated as trusted. Try to configure your SQL SEREVR to accept `Mixed Mode` connections.

Comment: The server is already changed to support both but still the same error

Comment: @jamesmews Does you restart SQL SERVER service after changing?

Comment: yep but it had no effect, do you know about IntegratedSecurity?

Comment: Ive got it working now thank you for response needed Integrated Security=SSPI at the end.

Comment: @jamesmews `Integrated Security=SSPI` allows you to login using windows account, this don't need you if you try to login using SQL Server login.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,I'm not sure but hope it will work-

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name ="conStr" connectionString ="Initial Catalog = projectDB; 
Data Source =JAMES-PC\SQLEXPRESS; User Id=james;Password=password;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

try mapping projectDB to user:james. open SQL Server Management Studio, select **Security - Logins**, double click user:**james**, select page:**User Mapping**, check projectDB.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following format If It is Sql Server user mode,

```
ConStr = "Server=JAMES-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=projectDB;User Id=james;
Password=password;"
```

if you are trying to connect using windows,

then you must provide `Trusted Connection = true`